# Dynamically consume and sink Kafka topics with Flink

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming

I haven't been able to find much information about this online. I'm wondering if its possible to build a Flink app that can dynamically consume all topics matching a regex pattern and sync those topics to s3. Also, each topic being dynamically synced would have Avro messages and the Flink app would use Confluent's Schema Registry.

Comment: Ho moku, I am looking to solve the same use case please help me out how you have done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lucky man! Flink 1.4 just released a few days ago and this is the first version that provides consuming Kafka topics using *REGEX*. According to java docs here is how you can use it:

> ### FlinkKafkaConsumer011

```
public FlinkKafkaConsumer011(PatternsubscriptionPattern,DeserializationSchema<T> valueDeserializer,Properties props)
```

> Creates a new Kafka streaming source consumer for Kafka 0.11.x. **Use
>   this constructor to subscribe to multiple topics based on a regular
>   expression pattern.** If partition discovery is enabled (by setting a
>   non-negative value for
>   *FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.KEY_PARTITION_DISCOVERY_INTERVAL_MILLIS* in the
>   properties), topics with names matching the pattern will also be
>   subscribed to as they are created on the fly.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> *subscriptionPattern* - The regular expression for a pattern of topic names to subscribe to.
>   *valueDeserializer* - The de-/serializer used to convert between Kafka's byte messages and Flink's objects.
>
> *props* - The properties used to configure the Kafka consumer client, and the ZooKeeper client.

Just **notice** that running Flink streaming application, it fetch topic data from Zookeeper at intervals specified using the consumer config :

```
FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.KEY_PARTITION_DISCOVERY_INTERVAL_MILLIS
```

It means every consumer should resync the metadata including topics, at some specified intervals.The default value is 5 minutes. So adding a new topic you should expect consumer starts to consume it at most in 5 minutes. You should set this configuration for Flink consumer with your desired time interval.

Comment: This is awesome man thanks so much for the info! I forgot to ask this question but do you know how to then dynamically sync each of the topics to s3 to different locations in s3. For instance a different s3 prefix for each topic?

Comment: @moku my pleasure, Sorry, I don't have any information about s3. You should open another discussion for it. If this answer helped, pls pls check it as the correct answer, it will be useful for the future questioner.

Comment: How can i set the interval?
I tried to do that:

`properties.setProperty("flink.partition-discovery.interval-millis", "20");`
`FlinkKafkaConsumer<> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("someReg_.*"), new CustomKafkaDeserializationSchema(), properties);`
but it didnt work/

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to Kafka topics with a regex pattern was added in Flink 1.4. See the [documentation here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-topic-and-partition-discovery).

S3 is one of the file systems supported by Flink. For reliable, exactly-once delivery of a stream into a file system, use the [flink-connector-filesystem connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/connectors/filesystem_sink.html).

You can configure Flink to use Avro, but I'm not sure what the status is of interop with Confluent's schema registry.

For searching on these and other topics, I recommend the search on the Flink doc page. For example: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/search-results.html?q=schema+registry